# ¿Por qué fue cerrada mi pregunta como duplicada cuando no lo es?

Tags: discusión

Soy usuario de este sitio desde hace dos días. Del mismo modo, también estoy comenzando a utilizar Python, es decir, para que se entienda, soy un principiante.

Además de la infinidad de tutoriales que uno puede encontrar por internet, soy consciente de que una manera eficaz de aprender a programar es intentando resolver problemas concretos, esto es, intentando resolver problemas reales que todos podemos entender leyendo un texto como nos enseñaron en el colegio (con lengua natural). Así pues, es lo que estoy intentando hacer, imaginar situaciones reales, describirlas e intentar simularlas con Python.

Hace un par de días aparecí por este sitio por primera vez para plantear mi primera pregunta, intentando definir el problema que había imaginado. Obviamente, igual que si hubiera llegado a un planeta donde usan un lenguaje que desconozco, desconozco gran parte del vocabulario que deseo aprender. A saber, para que se entienda bien, un extranjero es ANALFABETO. Pero que nadie se equivoque, eso no quiere decir que sea idiota, pues comprende las cosas con el mismo nivel de racionalidad lingüística con que cualquier otro ser humano está dotado.

Hasta la fecha he formulado dos preguntas:

1. [Almacenar valores en un diccionario](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38844/python-almacenar-valores-en-un-diccionario)
2. [Python aplicado a juego de señales](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/38918/python-aplicado-a-un-juego-de-se%C3%B1ales-generar-emparejamientos-y-asignar-valores)

Mi duda principal es: ¿por qué fue cerrada la segunda pregunta como duplicada de la primera?

Parten de lo anterior una serie de críticas constructivas que deseo dejar planteadas, desde mis primeras experiencias, para el bien del sitio (en el que espero seguir aprendiendo, y contribuir algún día), pensando que quizá puedan ser de utilidad. Allá van:

Primera reflexión:
Desde el primer momento he quedado muy sorprendido por el potencial del sitio. Mi primera pregunta fue respondida de manera ágil y rápida.

Segunda reflexión:
Si una pregunta es marcada como "duplicado exacto", debería ser por razones lógicas. Mis preguntas no son ni mucho menos duplicados. Pero si alguien considera que son la misma pregunta por favor que me diga por qué. Estoy dispuesto a rectificar.

Tercera reflexión:
Si una pregunta que no es un duplicado queda anulada no hay posibilidad de ulteriores respuestas. Por lo tanto el usuario principiante no aprende, lo que es manifiestamente inútil.

Cuarta reflexión:
Si una pregunta formulada por un usuario principiante está bien formulada pero no responde a un formato preestablecido por la comunidad, resultan también inoperantes e inútiles respuestas del tipo "no entiendo".

Quinta reflexión:
La utilidad educativa de un sitio no está definida por la satisfacción permanente del lenguaje concreto que se desea aprender, sino por la comprensión que la comunidad es capaz de tener sobre preguntas bien formuladas pero con otro lenguaje. En palabras llanas, es absolutamente inútil para un analfabeto escuchar "no te entiendo" en una lengua que no entiende.

Creo que estas tendencias están extendidas. Y desde mis percepciones de aprendiz, creo que la comunidad (generalizando mucho) debería intentar mejorar en estas cuestiones para ser un lugar verdaderamente efectivo desde los primeros pasos.

Comment: Tu opinión es realmente interesante y tus reflexiones también. Este sitio está basado en preguntas y respuestas, y el texto expuesto aquí luce como un grupo de ideas. ¿Tienes alguna pregunta en particular, quizás como "¿por qué se cerro como duplicada cuando no lo es? ¿se puede proveer alguna explicación al respecto?" o solo quieres brindar tus ideas?

Comment: Gracias por la respuesta. Sí, si es posible me gustaría saber por qué fue cerrada la pregunta como duplicada. Al mismo tiempo, como bien comentas, brindar mis percepciones para mejorar el foro.

Comment: Esto no es un foro, es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas. Acabo de actualizar tu publicación para reflejar la pregunta (es lo principal que debe entenderse en una publicación de pregunta) y luego tus reflexiones.

Comment: Excelente @pyring, eso me gusta leer, diferentes opiniones para poder mejorar como comunidad. Hay una cuestión, en lo personal, siento que tus reflexiones encajarían con un foro, en el cual se basan principalmente en opiniones, ideas, teorías, etc., donde los usuarios se colocan en los zapatos del OP. :( Desafortunadamente StackOverFlow en español es un sitio de preguntas y respuestas específicas bajo un estándar, de esa manera son aceptadas, de lo contario son rechazadas. Suena muy cruel pero es la única forma de mantener organizado y limpio el sitio :)

Comment: Gracias a Luiggi por reabrir la pregunta. Gracias a x4mp73r por el comentario. En efecto, preguntas específicas es lo que hice, no tertulia. El lenguaje (Python) lo tendré que aprender poco a poco como principiante humano que soy.

Comment: Fue cerrada porque hay pocos usuarios que sepan como cerrar preguntas y cuando tocar el boton "Omitr". Cuando tengamos los audits, muchos "revisores" quedaran suspendidos o aprenderán a no votar de lo que no saben. La cosa es que uno vota sin saber y 4 lo siguen sin pensar y sin leer. Es lamentable que estemos así, pero es uno de los problemas a solucionar en esta comunidad.

Comment: Coincido con @rnd. Como referencia, siempre es útil saber que todas las colas de revisión tienen su página y [aquí](http://es.stackoverflow.com/review/close/24005) podemos ver cómo fue valorado el caso por parte de la comunidad. Todo es accesible desde el [timeline de la pregunta](http://es.stackoverflow.com/posts/38918/timeline).

Comment: Tal como dicen algunos esto no es un foro, si no más bien un portal de preguntas y respuestas. Tambien comparto parte de lo que expones en tu post, en este sitio hay gente que no sabe y vota por cerrar, no comenta un "consejo" como : Hey, mejora tu pregunta, agrega el codigo... si no que cierran inmediatamente. Lo mismo pasa con las respuestas cuando son solo comentarios (basta con buscar en stack over flow en ingles y ver muchas respuestas aceptas, con muchos votos a favor sin ninguna linea de codigo) El criterio que ocupan algunos es egoista y autoritario por tener un par de puntos mas.